# List github issue revisions - octokit

Tags: javascript, github, github-api, octokit, probot

I'm developing a probot application to prevent disclosure of sensitive information on github issues.

When I edit out the sensitive information from the github-issue, the information can still be viewed on the post's edit history (revision history) where you can then manually delete them from the UI, as shown:
[Github-issues-revision-history and deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBtes.png)

I've been using https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18 but there doesn't seem to be a clear endpoint to access said revisions.

Tried various approaches such as

```
var promise=context.github.issues.listEvents({owner:"james", repo:"test-repo", issue_number:56})
   promise.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
})
```

but I can't seem to be able to find where those revisions are saved.
Where exactly are those post revisions saved so I can delete them using my probot application?

Comment: octokit API scrapes Github API Documentation so, as far as there is an API for it and it's published in Github API Documentation, it should be available. In a quick search I found the regular UI option as you mentioned but I did not find the REST API option on docs.github.com. If there's one, could you share it with us please? This way we can check if it's being scraped correctly.

Thanks

Comment: @OscarDOM I opened a git-issue with the creator of Probot and apparently there's no REST option to do what I want ( https://github.com/probot/probot/issues/1264 ). I've opened a ticket with github as well to see if this can get implemented in the future or if they have a way around it. For now, it looks like I'll have to go with GraphQL in addition to Probot.

Comment: The Rest API doesn't expose any endpoint for issue deletion. However, the GraphQL API does provide https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/deleteissue/ for deleting the issue. No endpoints to delete a specific revision though.

Comment: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#pagination helped me.